# Modify general community loading spinner

Tags: community

I'm trying to adjust the general spinner (loading balls) that is utilized throughout the entire standard Salesforce community (see example below).

[image]

I would like to modify the loading animation but currently I'm struggling how.
The standard Salesforce spinner itself is configured in the following div
[image]

I have searched throughout the entire web searching for means to modify/overwrite the standard behavior but to no avail.

Is there a general place to overwrite this behavior and if not, how could this be done programatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for your problem. You need to basically replace current div with after pseudo-element that will contain gif image of your spinner, for example:

[image: standard spinner animation]
OR
[image: brand spinner animation]

You can do it by editing your community CSS (in Builder by clicking Theme -> Edit CSS option or by creating custom CSS for your community in Static Resource) with this code:

```
.siteforceLoadingBalls.global {
    left: 38%;
}
.siteforceLoadingBalls {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.siteforceLoadingBalls:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: url(<your url>);
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

If you want to move your spinner to left or right, simply modify "left" param. Modifying the size also shouldn't be a problem.
To avoid any CSP (Content Security Policy) problems it is better to add your gif image to your Static Resource and pass the path to it in "your url". Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Perfectly solved the issue, thx!